# Change close button to right on Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME

Tags: 16.04, gnome, titlebar, window-buttons

I was initially on Unity desktop but I installed GNOME and I want to move the buttons to the right. I have tried commands like

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

but nothing happened actually. The result of `ls /usr/bin/*session*`

```
rxyz@rxyz:~$ ls /usr/bin/*session*
/usr/bin/dbus-run-session          /usr/bin/gnome-session-quit
/usr/bin/gnome-session             /usr/bin/session-installer
/usr/bin/gnome-session-classic     /usr/bin/session-migration  
/usr/bin/gnome-session-inhibit     /usr/bin/x-session-manager
/usr/bin/gnome-session-properties
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view the current position of the buttons, open Terminal and run

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout
```

To change it to the left run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout close,minimize,maximize:
```

or to change it to the right run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout :minimize,maximize,close
```

The position of window buttons is determined by the position of the **:** mark. If it's at the beginning, the buttons will be at the right; if it's at the end, the buttons will be at the left.

[Source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2348381)

Comment: You can also do this from `Preferences > Windows` then from the `Titlebar Buttons` dropdown change position to `Left` or `Right`.